# Faster inventory management

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, house-rules, encumbrance

I have tended to hand-wave weight limits and encumbering rules and focus on fun, but the bulk of random items starts to really build up to ridiculous levels (even with a bag of holding). Doing time-consuming inventory checks every few months seems more like a punishment for my players who enjoy coming up with creative solutions.

What is the simplest technique or house rule that you, as a DM or player, have used to *speed up* inventory management?

Comment: How can this question be improved? I'm interested in it

Comment: I like this question too, one of my DM's wants to try and account for weigh limits (With a party full of STR 8 characters lol) and techniques for ensuring it is captured would be very useful. Could this question be improved by simply asking for experiences rather than 'a list'?

Comment: @THadron In addition to asking how other DMs have successfully enforced/tracked inventory, you should also specify some criteria for what a good/correct answer looks like. You'll have to be specific with those criteria. For example, are you primarily concerned with inventory accuracy, gameplay speed, player satisfaction...? Are there any restrictions on techniques, such as no DM involvement in the purge, needs to be done frequently/only occasionally, ...? In order for the question to fit the SE format, there has to be a way to pick an objective best answer, hence the need for criteria.

Comment: While this is a good *question*, I don't think there's going to be a good *answer* until a genius game designer develops a way to track encumbrance without tracking encumbrance. (And when that game designer *does* finally develop that system, I expect almost every game designer thereafter will use it!)

Comment: Unfortunately, unless you give us criteria for what would be a good answer here, this is an idea generation question. How are you defining "better" for making gameplay better? Some tables may find full management better, others not, and some in between. What defines better for you and your table?

Comment: What do you mean by "meshes it with gameplay better"? Takes less time (in/out of the session)? Is more immersive? Makes players want to do it more often? Something else?

Comment: I really don't think this should be reopened until some of the questions above are answered specifically about what goals OP is trying to achieve here, what specific issue they are trying to solve and what they mean by "meshing with gameplay". Without these details, this question is just going to turn into an endless list of inventory management suggestions without any focus on solving the issues OP seems to have.

Comment: Perhaps this is a little tricky for SE format... But the focus here is definitely on speed and efficiency with minimal interruption. I think the "simplest" method is a good quantitative metric for judging answers. How can it be focused better to be asking about other gm's techniques/rules?

Comment: @THadron can I suggest you amend the final question to "technique or house rule", if you're open to suggestions for tools and what that don't involve changing the rules?

Comment: @NautArch I think the 5e inventory management system could be tweaked with a simple house rule if it helps speed things up.

Comment: I'm closing this because it needs adjustment in a way I can't provide as an editor. By asking "what's the fastest thing you personally have done?" this becomes [a survey](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) where every answer will be equally correct (they *are* all going to be the fastest thing any particular person has done) and not a concrete problem with a single best or correct answer. What this needs to ask is "I want to accomplish this particular goal, how can I do that?" where that goal is what you, THadron, want inventory management to be like in your game.